# In SCons, what is the advantage of using Configure() to set variables instead of Environment?

Tags: scons

In SCons examples, `CPPPATH` etc. are often set in `Configure()`. Is there an advantage to doing it there instead of just setting it on `Environment()` directly?

Comment: Configure is used to determine things about the current build environment. Usually intended for when you are distributing your software for others to build and you don't know what compilers, libraries,etc they will have installed.   If that doesn't apply then setting the CPPPATH, etc in your Environment() directly may be a simpler choice.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "are often set in `Configure()`". Please provide an example of the used syntax. Usually, when using the Configure context you execute a test...and then set environment variables based on its result. If you know that you always have to set a variable to a fixed value, then you don't need `Configure` at all.